# how do i make embedded pdf work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

why doesn't work when loading in it in device view
, i've tried `<embed><object><iframe>`
as soon as i turned it to web view it show up

check this example on device view to see the problem [here](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>title</title>

</head>

<body>
    <embed  src="pdf/file.pdf" ></embed >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the pdf url directs to an existing path? Can you also try to add width and height to the embed ?

Comment: @2hTu2 check this [example](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object` instead of `embed`

```
<object data="pdf/file.pdf" type="application/pdf">
</object>
```

Mobile browsers accept `object` tag

Comment: did you try it on [link](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/1085) and it worked ?

Comment: did you do it in this order ( f12 -> toggle device toolbar -> make the change -> submit ) ?

Comment: but how -.- , are you using chrome ?

Comment: Yeah, I am using chrome